# Magento2 How to get all store specific category if category is not include in menu?

Tags: category

I am using the below code to find store specific categories but here I am not getting the categories that are not included in the menu. How can I get those categories also?

```
    protected $_categoryHelper;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper

    )
    {
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    }

    public function getAllCurrentStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
    return $this->categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

      in template

// get current store's categories
$categories = $block->getAllCurrentStoreCategories();
foreach ($categories as $category) {    
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code.

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

$objectManager = $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore()); //categories from current store will be fetched

foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category->getName();
}
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Hi Mayur, Thanks for your respond, By using the above I am not getting store specific categories. the above code is returning all categories.

Comment: It will help you to fetch current store all categories.

Comment: Already verified I am having 2 different stores and websites it is returning all categories.